# How to add a key-up event on textbox to catch user's “tab” input

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a text box and I do a data validation on the text using a keyUp event. When keys like 'enter', 'Arrow Dn' are pressed my validation works. The only key I can't trap is the 'TAB' key. It's keycode is 09 but the event handler does not send the keycode, just 'N/A'. Is their a way to trap the 'TAB' key?

```
....
var textClient = app.createTextBox().setId('txtClient')
                                    .setName('txtClient')
                                    .setSize('200px', '25px')
                                    .setStyleAttributes(styleTEXT14)
                                    .addKeyUpHandler(app.createServerKeyHandler('keyUpClient'))
                                    .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('clickClient'));
panelMain.Add(textClient, x, y);
....


function keyUpClient(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var key = e.parameter.keyCode;
  var boxData = e.parameter.txtClient; 
  Logger.log(key);
....
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?  Show me what is working, and I will see if there is a way to do what you want, or if there is a way to get to the same end by a different means.  From this, I can only guess, and try to write something from scratch that is similar, and that is a lot of guesswork (and time wasting).

Comment: Is it bad to just assume 'N/A' == Tab then?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the same `keyUpHandler` to the next widget then you will get the keypress value even when you use the 'TAB' key, here is an example that works for the first textBox :

Test online [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxqpRyu_r5r6osO761VXL7gIriaP89yZNLf0GjRuBprd8UlaPCp/exec) *(strangely this does not work on my Android tablet, no idea why... but works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari)*

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var keyUpHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('keyUpClient');
  var textClient = app.createTextBox().setId('txtClient').setName('txtClient').addKeyUpHandler(keyUpHandler)
                                    .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('clickClient').addCallbackElement(panel));
  var text2 = app.createTextBox().addKeyUpHandler(keyUpHandler);
  app.add(panel.add(textClient)).add(text2);
  return app
}


function keyUpClient(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var key = e.parameter.keyCode;
  var boxData = e.parameter.txtClient; 
  app.add(app.createLabel('You pressed the key with code '+key));
  return app;
}

function clickClient(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  return app;
}
```

---

EDIT : there is a small issue in that code that I didn't notice immediately : the source of the handler when one presses the tab key is not the first textBox but the second, which is indeed logical in a way...
So if this is a problem for your use case, here is a workaround I tested on the demo app and that works.(online app updated with the following modified code)

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var keyUpHandler = app.createServerKeyHandler('keyUpClient');
  var textClient = app.createTextBox().setId('textBox1').setName('textBox1').addKeyUpHandler(keyUpHandler)
                                    .addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler('clickClient').addCallbackElement(panel));
  var text2 = app.createTextBox().addKeyUpHandler(keyUpHandler).setId('textBox2');
  app.add(panel.add(textClient)).add(text2);
  return app
}


function keyUpClient(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var key = e.parameter.keyCode;
  var boxData = e.parameter.textBox1; 
  var source = e.parameter.source;
  if(source=='textBox2'&& key=='9'){source='textBox1'}
  app.add(app.createLabel('You pressed the key with code '+key+' in textBox '+source));
  return app;
}
```